# Fastapi get router while other router works properly

Tags: fastapi

I am running my fast api on server in docker container ..when my container is restarting the get router is giving follwing error

"Error: [ValueError('dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required'), TypeError('vars() argument must have **dict** attribute')]"

I am using JSON response and jsonable encoder

Comment: You'll have to include a minimum, verifiable example that shows the issue - without any code it's hard for someone else to say anything useful. Generally you're probably returning an object when a dictionary was expected.

Comment: Data is not getting fetched in get router from those models that I have applied relationship after my docker container got restart